# How to decode a PNG image in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, rust, encoding, png, decoding

I was building a tool to extract images in a PDF file using Rust. For now I can extract all other images except PNG.

I used a crate called `pdf` to extract the images.

```rust
let mut images: Vec<_> = vec![];

    for page in file.pages() {
        let page = page.unwrap();

        let resources = page.resources()?;

        images.extend(
            resources
                .xobjects
                .iter()
                .map(|(_name, &r)| file.get(r).unwrap())
                .filter(|o| matches!(**o, pdf::object::XObject::Image(_))),
        )
    }
```

Now depending upon the filter I set the format

```rust
for (i, o) in images.iter().enumerate() {
        let img = match **o {
            XObject::Image(ref im) => im,
            _ => continue,
        };

        let (data, filter) = img.raw_image_data(&file)?;

        use StreamFilter::*;

        let ext = match filter {
            Some(DCTDecode(_)) => "jpeg",
            Some(JBIG2Decode) => "jbig2",
            Some(JPXDecode) => "jp2k",
            _ => {
                log::debug!("main : unsupported image format");
                continue;
            }
        };
```

The problem arises when PNG images are in a PDF file. The `filter` is always a `None` value. So I tried to experiment a little bit by using the `image` crate to decode the PNG image.

```rust
for (i, o) in images.iter().enumerate() {
        let img = match **o {
            XObject::Image(ref im) => im,
            _ => continue,
        };

        let (data, filter) = img.raw_image_data(&file)?;

        use StreamFilter::*;

        let ext = match filter {
            Some(DCTDecode(_)) => "jpeg",
            Some(JBIG2Decode) => "jbig2",
            Some(JPXDecode) => "jp2k",
            _ => {
                let img = image::io::Reader::new(Cursor::new(data.clone()))
                    .with_guessed_format()?
                    .decode()?;
                "png"
            }
        };
```

But on running the code I got

```bash
Error: Unsupported(UnsupportedError { format: Unknown, kind: Format(Unknown) })
```

I tried to read the [PDF 1.7 reference document](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and then used `flate2` library to decompress the data but I got

```bash
Error : Invalid Signature
```

How should I proceed from here ?

Comment: There's a tool called `pdfimages` in the `poppler` package that might give you some insights as to whether your PDF is correct, and contains a PNG and how big it is etc.

Comment: PNGs/BMPs and such format are a raw `/FlateDecode`-stream in PDFs. You'll need to get the `/Width`-, `/Height`- and `/BitsPerComponent`-parameters, and construct a raw image from the pixel data yourself. Look around here on SA, there are numerous questions with respect to PNG/BMP in PDF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG images are not included in a PDF file directly (unlike JPEG and JPEG2000, for example), so you cannot extract them directly.

You also cannot do JBIG2Decode directly - it is more complicated than you suppose.

For PNG, The data in the FlateDecode stream is just the IDAT chunk from the PNG. You must reconstruct the IHDR chunk from, for example /Width and /Height and /BPC and /ColourSpace, and then write the PNG file yourself, calculating checksums and building chunks according to the PNG standard.

Comment: I learned something new today - thank you.

Comment: Btw, even in case of JPG images, you have to take the values in the stream dictionary into account, there sometimes are relevant changes in regard to e.g. the color space of the image data.